# How do I programmatically taint the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, root

Is it possible to taint a running Linux kernel programatically? I want to be able to test things with a tainted kernel, without recompiling it to make it tainted or finding a proprietary kernel module to load.

Comment: You should also be able to compile a trivial module of your own, that doesn't do anything but whose `MODULE_LICENSE` is missing or not GPL-compatible.  The kernel will consider it "proprietary" and taint itself. You don't have to go out and find a genuinely proprietary module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `root` user can taint the kernel [by writing a taint value to `/proc/sys/kernel/tainted`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/34f5a39899f3f3e815da64f48ddb72942d86c366). Taint flags can only be set (not removed) in this way: there is no way to untaint a running kernel. When writing a value to indicate that userspace has done something weird, you should use `TAINT_USER` (which has a value of `32`). For example (as `root`):

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/tainted
64
# echo 32 > /proc/sys/kernel/tainted
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/tainted
96
```